# Two time formats in date()?

Tags: php

How could I do to put two different date formats?

In my code...

```
        $month = date('n');
    $day = date('j');
    $year = date('Y');

    $request = $DBFunc['db_query']('', '
        SELECT COUNT(duedate)
        FROM {db_prefix}dulas
        WHERE is_did = {int:is_did}
            AND MONTH(duedate) = {int:month}
            AND DAYOFMONTH(duedate) = {int:day}
            AND YEAR(duedate) >= {int:year}',
        array(
            'is_did' => 0,
            'year' => $year,
            'month' => $month,
            'day' => $day,
        )
    );
```

Month and days is without leading zeros, but I would also like it to check with zeros as well, ie 'd' and 'm' formats, how can I do that?

No working ej: $month = date('n' || 'm')...

Thanks.

Put two formats in date.

Comment: The first question is, what date format/column type do you actually use in your database? I don't know what your query function does under the hood, however your placeholders are marked as `{int:month}` etc. and assuming the variables are actually cast to integers, then `(int) '05'` is `5`, since decimal integers retain no leading zeros. Which would make your concern moot.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently do something similar, where I want one formatted for people to read easily and another for computations that need the leading zero.  I double-up the code so I have two variables for month, 2 variables for the day, then I can use whichever I need where I need them in my code/output.  It isn't fancy but I believe in keeping it simple.

Comment: Computations that need a leading zero? Computations typically happen with decimal integers, which do not have leading zeros.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I like to format the date as 20230705 to compare with another date.  Easy to do the math and easier to read than the EPOCH date/time.  Of course 202375 would not work in this case